# Karate CLI Testing - Execute Command within context of another Command

Tags: testing, command-line-interface, karate

I'm currently testing a CLI app written by a developer in my team - specifically this command:

```
./mycli init
```

After entering this command, it responds with this:

```
Enter endpoint:
```

As suggested, I need to provide the target URL, then hit enter.
I'll then be asked 2 more questions which require input.

For example, let's say I have this:

```
* def listener =
    """
    function(line) {
      if (line.contains('Enter endpoint')) {
        //input the answer
      }
    }
    """

* def initCmd = karate.fork({ args: ['sh','mycli','init'], listener: listener })
* print initCmd.sysOut
```

(NB: This snippet was inspired by `fork-listener.feature` and this interesting thread with jbang team https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1191)

Karate is working really well for all the other tests I need to do for this CLI - is there something I can put in the IF statement for this particular use case?

Comment: sorry, this sounds hard. there's also an open issue with the latest version of karate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2211 - your best bet is to contribute code and collaborate with others if needed

Comment: also one suggestion is see if you can influence that developer to implement a "silent" mode, where the answers are pulled from environment variables. does that make sense ?

Comment: Fair enough, I'm an average coder at best :) - but when I get some downtime I'll certainly take a look. 

Yep makes sense and agree with you on that. Thanks for the swift response